# Python: BeautifulSoup cannot parse html page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse [this URL](http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/FTO/FTOReport.aspx?page=s&mode=B&flg=W&state_name=BIHAR&state_code=05&fin_year=2018-2019&dstyp=B&source=national&Digest=2H3ATbXXBsabT72RmlXODw).

I am using requests and BeautifulSoup.

Python requests successfully gets the page.

I have tried printing page content to see whether it has any or not. It has contents but doesn't know why BeautifulSoup can't parse it. It's stuck there program does not move forward.

I tried with `lxml` as parser too but didn't work.

Code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/FTO/ResponseDetailStatusReport.aspx?lflag=&flg=W&page=s&state_name=BIHAR&state_code=05&district_name=ARARIA&district_code=0541&fin_year=2018-2019&typ=R&mode=B&source=national&Digest=RZw1g4RnMeHsOzbabiNGBg"

reference_page = requests.get(url)

print(" Total time to get page in seconds : "+str(reference_page.elapsed.total_seconds()))

print('\t Reference Page status : '+ str(reference_page))
print(reference_page.content)

reference_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(reference_page.content,'html.parser')
print("\n \t Page parsed")
```

Comment: Perhaps because the page is ginormous. It just takes a very long time to get it all done.

Comment: @BramVanroy sir the length of content is 18363295. Is it too big ?

Comment: This is server problem (It takes a lot of time to connect). This is not problem of BeautifulSoup. calculate time of requests.get(url) and let us now results.

Comment: `get()` takes too much to get the page. It looks there is a server problem. And the page display this: > URL TEMPERED

Comment: @BramVanroy @gachdavit I don't think the problem is with the server as it only takes around 5 seconds for me to open (with `urllib.request.urlopen`). And I don't think the page is that big! I've surely parsed pages longer than that.

Comment: I guess get() might take time if you are trying from outside India. It shouldn't show URL Tampered because I am trying from hours and not got this response.

Comment: @user8810517 I'm outside India, and I don't get that response as well. But it takes `BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')` almost 10 minutes to complete!

Comment: @gachdavit it took 4.729337 seconds. If you see my code just after get() there is page response print statement. It gets printed quickly that me means page gets loaded quickly. I am updating code with a line to print request time in seconds.

Comment: @AmirAShabani yes. Also the page isn't that big but don't know why BeautifulSoup is that slow.

Comment: I added answer. check it and analyze.

Comment: @AmirAShabani  Upgrading my packages worked. Please check my answer .You too try upgrading the packages but one by one to know which package had issue because I just updated all of them at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked is I updated following three packages.

I should have upgraded the packages one by one to see which one really had the issue.

Then too following packages were updated :

1. Requests

```py
pip install requests --upgrade
```

2. BeautifulSoup

```
pip install beautifulsoup --upgrade
```

3. lxml

```
pip install lxml --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all server response is an extremely slow. But, even read same content from local file and pass it to `BeautifulSoup`, it takes a lot of time. ~4 seconds for me (4 seconds just for `BeautifulSoup` initialization without parsing. Big time). I made little research. From `BeautifulSoup.__init__` method `self._feed()` method is called, which on the other hand calls `LXMLTreeBuilder.feed()` (This is very **time-consuming** operation. This is reason why your `BeautifulSoup` instance creation is so slow). Use plain `LXML` library if time is so important for you.

```
import lxml.html

#URL = "http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/FTO/ResponseDetailStatusReport.aspx?lflag=&flg=W&page=s&state_name=BIHAR&state_code=05&district_name=ARARIA&district_code=0541&fin_year=2018-2019&typ=R&mode=B&source=national&Digest=RZw1g4RnMeHsOzbabiNGBg"
# response = requests.get(URL)


html = lxml.html.parse('test.html') # Now I am reading test.html from my local disk. you can load data on local disk or try to parse directly from external data. find in documentation
table = html.xpath('//table')
print(table[0].xpath('//td')[0].text)
```

[lxml doc.](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html)

Comment: I want to use BeautifulSoup library beacuse want to use its functions. PS.: I didn't downvote the answer.

Comment: Do not worry about downvote. I described why it was so slow, in details. I do not think, that you can speed up BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Upgrading my packages worked. Please check my answer .You too try upgrading the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `html.parser` use `lxml`. For me the entire process tookless than 5 secs. 
I used the following code.

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/FTO/FTOReport.aspx?page=s&mode=B&flg=W&state_name=BIHAR&state_code=05&fin_year=2018-2019&dstyp=B&source=national&Digest=2H3ATbXXBsabT72RmlXODw'

resp = rq.get(url).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, "lxml")
```

For my Python installation **Requests** package is at version **2.21.0**, **BeautifulSoup4** is at version **0.0.1** and **lxml** is at version **4.2.5**. lxml parser is way faster than the html.parser.

Comment: I did had same version but didn't worked. I upgraded all the packages and it worked.